# Why does using Displacement vector doesn't give the correct result for the surface charge density of an infinite dielectric slab below a point charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, dielectric, displacement

> Find the force on a point charge $q$ placed a distance $d$ above the XY plane with the region $z<0$ filled with dielectric with susceptibilty $\chi_{e}$.
> (From Griffiths EM, Example 4.8)

The author employs two methods, one which calculates the z component of the net electric field at a point $\mathbf{r}$ from origin in the XY plane and then use it in the relation $\sigma_{b} = P_z = \chi_e \epsilon_0E_z$ to find $\sigma_b$. The other one uses the familiar Image Method, both of which makes perfect sense. The surface charge density comes out to be:

$$\sigma_b = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\chi_e}{\chi_e+2}\frac{qd}{(r^2+d^2)^{3/2}}$$

However, I tried to do it on my own with the use of Displacement Vector D. Here's how I proceed:
$$\oint_{\mathcal{S}}\mathbf{D\cdot}d\mathbf{a} = Q_{f\,encl}$$

where $\mathcal{S}$ is the gaussian surface, a sphere centered at $q$ with radius $\mathcal{R}$, therefore

$$D\cdot(4\pi\mathcal{R}^2) = q$$ $$\text{or}\;\;\mathbf{D} = \frac{q\mathbf{\hat{\mathcal{R}}}}{4\pi\mathcal{R}^2}\;,\;\;\text{everywhere}$$

$$\text{so,}\;\;\mathbf{E}=\frac{\mathbf{D}}{(1+\chi_e)\epsilon_0}=\frac{q\mathbf{\hat{\mathcal{R}}}}{4\pi(1+\chi_e)\epsilon_0\mathcal{R}^2}$$

$$\therefore\;\;\mathbf{P}=\chi_e\epsilon_0\mathbf{E}=\frac{\chi_eq\mathbf{\hat{\mathcal{R}}}}{4\pi(1+\chi_e)\mathcal{R}^2}\;\;\text{, just below the surface, inside the dielectric}$$

Now, $\sigma_b$ will be then just $\mathbf{P\cdot\hat{n}}$, where $\mathbf{\hat{n}=\hat{k}}$ and $\mathbf{\mathcal{R}=r-}d\mathbf{\hat{k}}$. So,

$$\sigma_b = \frac{\chi_eq\mathbf{\hat{\mathcal{R}}\cdot\hat{k}}}{4\pi(1+\chi_e)\mathcal{R}^2} = - \frac{\chi_eqd}{4\pi(1+\chi_e)\mathcal{R}^{3}}\;\;\text{as,}\;\mathbf{\hat{\mathcal{R}}\cdot\hat{k}} = - \frac{d}{\mathcal{R}}$$

$$\text{i.e.,}\;\;\;\sigma_b = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{\chi_e}{1+\chi_e}\frac{qd}{\mathcal{R}^{3}}$$

which comes out to be different from the one found above, surely something has gone wrong, but I am not able to make out what am I missing here.
**Although I have used the correct equations but it seems that they do not apply nicely in this case, for which I am unsure of why the displacement method does't work here, what difference does it causes from the above two methods.** Is it ok @ACuriousMind?

Comment: Your series of steps to find $D$ in terms of coordinates makes no sense. The system has no spherical symmetry.

Comment: It doesn't, but the displacement vector doesn't differentiate from material to material(isn't it?), so I thought that it still exists for the D, also in the step of finding the Electric field, the point is fixed on the XY plane, with $\mathbf{r=}x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf{j}$ and $\mathbf{\mathcal{R} = r-}d\mathbf{k}$

Comment: Displacement vector $\mathbf D$ depends on both electric field and polarization. It is not just function of free charge. Only divergence of $\mathbf D$ is function of free charge.

Comment: Yes! Sure it does infact the only reason I decided to try this method was to see whether using this argument (that div D is enough for finding D), I could get the same result, For, the textbook uses it in earlier examples, like charged line of wire covered cylindrically by a dielectric of some thickness, or charged conducting sphere inside a bigger dielectric sphere

Comment: Those are highly symmetrical systems where D shares the symmetry and can be easily found. In case of point charge near dielectric half-space there does not seem to be such a simple way.

Comment: Why does it require for D to share the symmetry?

Comment: This sort of thing is hard to explain here. In general, the equation $\nabla\cdot \mathbf D = \rho_f$ can't be solved for $\mathbf D$ in simple form. Only in special highly symmetric cases this can be done. Maybe it can be done in your case, but it is by no means obvious.

Comment: One way to see this: in the other cases you mention (sphere, cylinder), the symmetry is high enough that the field has the same magnitude on some surface (sphere, cylinder mantle). In the case of charge and half-space, there is no such obvious surface; the symmetry isn't high enough.

Comment: @JánLalinský thanks, found the answer after smashing my head on this problem for that whole day, yes the spherical symmetry isn't correct here to be usable, for at the interface where the spherical gaussian surface and the dielectric surface meet, the D exhibit discontinuity is parallel component along the xy plane, inside the dielectric, the symmetry is spherical but, the size of sphere and its center gets shifted(perhaps not the center shift), exactly what image method employs. Can you confirm your thought process too? thanks so much!